# Does it make sense to build 2 models - one for prediction and one for inference?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, inference, prediction

I am considering using a Generalised Additive model for prediction and a Generalised Mixed effects model for inference to explain the relationship between variables, so I can play to the strengths of the two model types.

Does this make sense to do? Or is it recommended to build only one model and have a compromise between explanatory power and predictive power?

Comment: @RyanVolpi I plan to use one model to explain the effect of the predictors on the response variable (using a GLMM which is more interpretable), and another model to predict the response more accurately (usign a GAM which will give a more accurate forecast as it allows a curve instead of forcing a linear relationship)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do whatever you want to forecast, even though it might not *explain* the relationship.

If you're interested in forecasting, then you will measure the performance of your model based on it's forecasting power. This indeed might not explain any relationship at all.